# Select latest inserted record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has (SubId, QId, Question, AnswerOptions, Ans). SubId is a foreign Key and QId is Primary key. my need is select latest inserted record and display it in to text box.

I already tried to these queries

```
SELECT * FROM tblQuestions 
 SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY ()


SELECT MAX(QId) FROM tblQuestions


 SELECT TOP 1 QId 
 FROM tblQuestions 
 ORDER BY QId DESC
```

but I get the first record, when I inserted at the first time, even I tried `MAX()` it shows the value 1, I tried `MIN()` it shows 1 also. How to I get latest value?

Note: the latest value is Maximum value of the QId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this will work

```
;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, r = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY QId DESC)
   FROM tblQuestions
)
SELECT * 
FROM x 
WHERE r = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Qld is a varchar type, this should work:

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM tblQuestions
ORDER BY Qld ASC
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT Qld FROM tblQuestions
ORDER BY Qld ASC
LIMIT 1
```

MS Access:

```
SELECT LAST(Qld) 
FROM tblQuestions
```

Comment: it should not work. QId is Varchar(50). but i inserted 1,2,3... when i trying this Query i get the value "1". not max value or last inserted value)

Comment: Using `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblQuestions ORDER BY Qld DESC` should work. Are you sure there's more data in the tables than just the initial one?

Comment: I just recreated this and tested it, changing to `ORDER BY Qld ASC` worked. Updating answer

Comment: this is working ;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, r = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY QId DESC)
   FROM tblQuestions
)
SELECT * 
FROM x 
WHERE r = 1;

Comment: this table has SubId, QId, Question, AnsOption,Ans columns. SubId has foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH get AS 
(
   SELECT 
     *, row = ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY qid DESC)
  FROM tbl
)
SELECT * 
FROM get 
WHERE row = 1;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I will make it by next time

Answer (score -1):

Look into: [Scope_identity](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

```
SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

The table which is having Identity Property from that table we can get the last inserted record id will be like this

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: no, when i use this function i get first row. that i inserted at the first time.